# Maven/Gradle working overlay example with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, gradle

I have an EAR project which should contain one or more skinny WARs. I already tried everything to get that project working with eclipse but just couldn't make eclipse do the same as the tools(maven and gradle) do when I run them from the command line.

Are there no working examples I could use to get my projects working with eclipse? Please help me, I alread ask myself if anyone is really using these tools like I want them to for such kind of projects.

Comment: Could you clarify what is not working by giving what you have yet tried? What does "contain one more more skinny WARs" mean? I thought WARs are a build artifact and are (only) created after having used your preferred build tool. When Eclipse starts an EAR project, does it first build the EAR? How do you do that?

Comment: I am asking for an example not a solution to the problems I had. I am looking for an example EAR project that contains one or more WAR projects. The libraries of the WAR projects should be moved to EAR/libs => skinny WAR. I now want an working example of an EAR Multimodule project with skinny WARs for either a maven or gradle project that also works within eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

In my last project experience I have problem with supporting the maven with Eclipse. Because of problem in Eclipse m2 plugin.

So the best solution for me was build an ear from the command line by some shell scripts for example. To open project in IDE I used [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html), thus I generated eclipse workspace by maven.

Using [Eclipse External Tools](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-exttools-running.htm) you can run shell script to build/or run your EE application from the command line pretty convenient.

The same applies to the gradle, but looks like Eclipse Gradle plugin is more stable, and now I use plugin in my Gradle project.

If it will be useful for you, you can review [github test project](https://github.com/JTaky/Tournament) to illustrate how to make maven multymodule war project. Also you can find short explanation how to generate eclipse workspace for this project. After workspace generated you can import as Existing Project into your workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I already tried so much and was explicitly asking for an example. If you provide me a maven/gradle example project that shows how skinny wars can be achieved so that also eclipse can handle it your answer will get accepted :)

Comment: I have only war example to show how to create maven project and I have added short explanation how to export project into eclipse.

Comment: The problems come when having an EAR project that should contain all libraries of the WAR project(s), would be cool if you could get that working in eclipse ;)

Comment: In the eclipse:eclipse workspace generation no differences you use war or ear project. Are you able to build EAR from command line?

Comment: I just found the solution for the maven build. In addition to make the skinny WAR work within eclipse one should not only use `packagingExcludes` but also `dependentWarExcludes`. Unfortunately I still cannot get the gradle projects working with eclipse. Maybe I should stick to maven then. I could offer you the accept if you can show me the following as gradle project working within eclipse: https://github.com/beikov/maven-multi-module-ear-skinny-war

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Ear project containing war(Refer to img below for dir structure)

**MainDir contain 2 files and 1 directory called war**.

File **settings.gradle** contains

```
include 'war'
```

File **build.gradle** contains

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    deploy project(':war')
    //earlib group: YOUR_DEPENDENCIES
}
```

build.gradle for **war** directory contains

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty' // you can call gradle jRW

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //compile group: YOUR_DEPENDENCIES
}

httpPort = 8080 //jetty start port
stopPort = 8081 //jetty stop port
```

File **HelloWorld.java** contains

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

File **index.jsp** contains

```
<jsp:useBean id="helloWorld" class="your_package.HelloWorld"/>
<html>
<p>${helloWorld.hello}</p>
</html>
```

Now open cmd->MainDir(or you can search eclipse-marketplace for gradle and execute this step directly from eclipse) and type

```
gradle jRW//short for jettyRunWar
```

now open

```
localhost:8080/war/
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but the question was about skinny wars within ears and such a gradle project working with eclipse. In the comments is a link to a maven project that does what I want, it even works with eclipse. I would just like to have a gradle version of it :(

Comment: How about if you modify the example and in war->build.gradle add the following `war { classpath =[]}` and then run `gradle ear`?

Comment: Can eclipse handle that? I already tried different approaches, not sure about this one, but I don't think this will work. I will try it and let you know. Since the gradle eclipse plugin can't handle dependency scopes as far as I have recognized, I also don't think it will produce valid project files with this setting.